# Изменение Inline кнопки aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=None)
async def starter(message):
    kp = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn1')
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn2')
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn3')

    btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn4')
    btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn5')
    btn6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn6')

    btn7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn7')
    btn8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn8')
    btn9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn9')
    kp.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
    kp.add(btn4, btn5, btn6)
    kp.add(btn7, btn8, btn9)
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Генерация поля', reply_markup=kp)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def back(call):
    if call.data == 'btn1':
        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌')
```

Нужно чтобы при нажатии например на btn1, сама кнопка менялась на крестик.
Через машину состояний тоже думаю бахнуть, но мне НЕ нужно, чтобы бот отсылал что-либо в чат, пользователь нажал на кпопку и она поменялась.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
    async def back(call):
        if call.data == 'btn1':
            btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❌')
```

Прекрасно понимаю, что вот эта часть ничего не даст.

Как обычно - готового решения не жду (а может и жду)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda call: True)
async def back(call):
    if call.data == 'btn1':

        kp = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

        btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тестовый код', callback_data='Тест')
        btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn2')
        btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn3')

        btn4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn4')
        btn5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn5')
        btn6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn6')

        btn7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn7')
        btn8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn8')
        btn9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='❤', callback_data='btn9')
        kp.add(btn1, btn2, btn3)
        kp.add(btn4, btn5, btn6)
        kp.add(btn7, btn8, btn9)

        await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id, reply_markup=kp)
```

Сработало вот таким кодом.